# Rename file from xx_02.csv to xx.csv

Tags: matlab

I have a folder 'a' with about 200 files with names xx_out_02.csv and I want to rename them to xx_out.csv. May be using Matlab or running some script. I tried it in cmd but I have to run the command for each and every file.
Can someone help me here?

Best Regards
Dilip

Comment: do they have sequential names? I'm not getting it.

Comment: What other files are there in the folder, and what are the target names? Please tell the general rule; don't make us guess. For instance, is there a `xx_out_02.csv` file? What would be the target name for it?

Comment: @SamuelNLP: yeah they are sequential names.. xx_02 to xx_200.

Comment: OK, then, what are the target names? from what to what?

Comment: I have a folder 'a' with about 200 files with names 'xx_out_02.csv' and I want to rename them to 'xx_out.csv'. I guess I mentioned this in the question itself.  xx is sequential from 1 to 200.

Comment: No, you didn't mention it. Please include it in your question. Also, as that `_02` fixed or does it vary? If so, how can it vary? Please also specify this

Comment: @Luis Mendo: xx varies from x1 to x200 and 02 is fixed, its just 02 all the time and no other numbers. I hope this clears your doubt. thank you.

Comment: @LuisMendo: the part in quotes is mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Dilip You didn't mention "xx is sequential from 1 to 200". And that's important

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `movefile`function from `matlab`.

Here is an example:

```
clc

addpath('yourdir')

csvf = dir('yourdir/*.csv');
numberOfcsv = numel(csvf);

for ii = 1:numberOfcsv
    file = csvf(ii).name;

    movefile(sprintf('yourdir/%s', file), sprintf('yourdir/x%03d_out.csv', ii), 'f');
end
```

Comment: Good idea to use `movefile`, which is independent of OS. But are you building target file as per the question? (Not that the question is very clear, anyway)

Comment: @LuisMendo, yeah, you are right. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear. I'm assuming

- You want to strip off substrings of the form *`_` followed by one or more digits* right before `.csv`.
- The resulting target names are all different. For example, you have files such as `xx_out_02.csv` and `yy_out_01.csv`, but not `xx_out_02.csv` and `xx_out_01.csv`.
- Operating system? I'm considering Windows. For other systems you can change the `system` line below with the appropriate system comand. Or better use `movefile` as in [SamuelNLP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30914177/2586922).

Code:

```
files = dir('*.csv');
names = {files.name};
for n = 1:numel(names)
    name = names{n};
    name_new = regexprep(name, '_\d+(?=\.csv$)', '');
    system(['ren ' name ' ' name_new]); %// MS-DOS command to rename file
end
```

Comment: you could use `filesep` instead of \ for the system problem

Comment: @titus.andronicus Thanks. But there's still the problem of the command itself: `ren` in Windows. `mv` in Linux etc

Comment: now I understand! Sorry for my confusion. I would have done the whole thing on bash, but I guess it's the OPs choice :)